# Exporting JPEG from WebODM takes ages

Tags: orthophoto

I have a largeish (~1000 images) orthomap which was created correctly in WebOSM.  When I try to export it as a JPEG (or anything else), nothing seems to happen.  The computer is working *very* hard (GPU and memory use is very high) but nothing seems to come of it, even more than an hour later (assembling the orthomap in the first place took approx 90 mins)

- How long should it realistically take?
- We have image resizing on already
- What have I done wrong/what should I do to export the composite?

Comment: Maximum size of a JPEG image is 65,535×65,535 pixels. Do you hit this limit?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. A bullet list of questions is likely to result in closure votes. Please [Edit] the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Structure from motion (SfM) reconstructions are very resource intensive.  SfM reconstruction times vary based on the number of images (and 1,000 is a lot of images), the pixel count of your images, whether you have a multi-spectral camera, your desired output quality, your computer RAM, and the power of your graphics card.  [See this link](https://community.opendronemap.org/t/is-there-any-limit-of-the-number-of-images-uploaded-for-one-project/5987) for some clues and to connect with the ODM online help.

You should include some information about your inputs, your computing power, and your input parameter although this is likely not enough to prevent your post from being closed.